# OSX: Text to Slides

Tags: macos, presentations, slideshow

I'm looking for a Mac OSX app that simply takes a text file I've written and converts it to pretty presentation slides, preferably as a PDF.  A simple markup language in the style of Markdown would be used for formatting.

There are a few online programs and Ruby/Python scripts for doing something like that, and the output is typically HTML:
http://groups.google.com/group/webslideshow

Is there anything like this for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

I've used OmniOutliner to create outlines for presentations, and then used the results of that with [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/). It's not really Mac-only (just use alternatives to OO on other platforms) and I've been happy with the result.